# Multi System Database structure based copying/updating best practice

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, copying

so after searching and not finding similar cases I want to open a new question.
So here is the case:
We are working with a large database with a very complicated data structure. Also we are working on multiple systems to ensure stability (development, testing, quality and productive) and its always a struggle so move data between those systems. As I said the data structure is very large and there is also a lot of logic inside the database. Customers are able to add new data parts as configuration and there is also a static income of data which are used for statistics and monitoring. So let me explain the problem with a small example:

[image]

Lets take this Database as an example. We have some families making some contest with each other. And they will create some statistics about the points they make.

- The Purple Tables are fixed configurations. They are created once and they can only be changed via an Operator. Those changes will be done and tested in the development system first.
- The Yellow Tables are changing configurations. Each Family is able to create or delete multiple Contests and assign their kids.
- The Red Table is just plain data. Each time a kid makes points, a new row is added with the amount and current time and the relation to the kid and contest.
  This table will be the base for the later statistics.

This Database is developed on two systems a productive one which is used by the families and a develop system which is used by the programmers/operators.

While developing the programmers will add test data like kids families contests and points. And while using the families will create new contests and assign new kids and will fill up the point table.

- It's necessary to copy new/tested/fixed families from the development to the productive system.
- Its also necessary to copy Contests, Contest-Kid-Assignments and Points from the productive to the development system to find new errors.
- Also it must be possible to change the table structure on the development system and transmit this change to the productive system. (This shouldn't be the main topic here sometimes it can be such a large changes that there just is no easy way, so lets keep this point simple but keep it in mind.)

I want to copy parts of the tables to another system but be able to ignore some tables (for example: Points) and I want to make sure to not copy kids without their parent family so there is no "parentless" object in the database.

**Question:** What would be a good and save way to do this?

I don't need a solution for a specific database type or some scripts. I'm looking for tools, libraries or good practice. (But just as a note we're using mssql.)

We are currently making a tool for this problem (not going well: unstable, overly complicated, slow and possible reinventing the wheel).

Also a lot of devs I know just copy the whole database (making a backup and running it into another server) But this is also making problems: users are being copied and their guid change so they loose permissions etc. I don't think this is a good solution. Also the database is down for quite a long time and its never a smooth process.

Making it manually is sometimes the easiest way but considering the size of our data structure its not just a huge piece of work there is also a large possibility for mistakes.

So I'm hoping someone knows a tool or something similar to help me out.

Comment: *It's necessary to copy new/tested/fixed families from the development to the productive system.* -- short answer: database seeding, **it depends on what technology stack you have**, nodejs can use [squelize](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/migrations.html), entity framework from [C# also had seeding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/data-seeding), [laravel also had seeding](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/migrations), etc etc.

Comment: also try your luck on [Software Engineering Stackexchange](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com). but again, probably people will just say, **seeding**.

Comment: There is some automatic seeding for mssql but this is only available for cluster licence which is currently not in the budget.

Comment: If you know you use MS SQL why add all the tags except MS SQL? As for your question, maybe some SSIS packages?

Comment: " I'm looking for tools, libraries or good practice."...asking for tools or libraries is off-topic, unfortunately. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic . The reasons are pretty valid IMHO.

Comment: "It's necessary to copy new/tested/fixed families from the development to the productive system"...why? Surely test data is test data, it should not overwrite live data?? Also you mentioned about different IDs etc so it's not clear how this would really be practical anyway?

Comment: "change the table structure on the development system and transmit this change to the productive system"...there are definitely SQL comparison tools which can help you with identifying schema differences. Some are installable into visual studio. SQL Server Data Tools I think it's called, you can search for it. Or you can just keep careful track of your schema changes and script them out into source control, then when you come to deploy you can run the scripts in the correct order. That's the traditional methodology.

Comment: " copy Contests, Contest-Kid-Assignments and Points from the productive to the development system" personally I'd just have some ready-to-run script templates to do an export and then import. Maybe via SSIS if the databases are accessible to each other, or via a dump to CSV and file transfer if not. You can just alter the IDs to get the live records you specifically want to target each time you run it. Note that in many jurisdictions (e.g. those covered by GDPR) you're normally expected to anonymise data which is not used for live purposes, unless test usage is authorised by the data subjects.

Comment: @ADyson ""...productive system"...why?": Some of the configuration is so complicated/difficult its considered as developing and done by programmers and also tested by project leaders and customers first.

Comment: @ADyson "keep careful track of your schema changes and script them out into source control": Yes that's the way currently. its also making problems because of how people work but that's sometime just the only way. (depending on the change size)

Comment: so in that case I would say this is patching of config data, so the scripts which generate the changes to the data would be source-controlled and then simply executed on the live system when ready. Again that's a fairly traditional approach but it should be effective if done properly. If people are not following this kind of process correctly already then maybe you need to implement some better guidance / training / having a word with them and also potentially have a review / gatekeeping and better testing process to double-check. You could test on a recent copy of live to verify scripts.

Comment: That was an approach the team took in a previous job. If we had a significant or complex set of patches to apply we would generally take the day before's backup of live, run the candidate patch scripts and check they didn't error and also did not produce other unexpected problems. If that passed then the patches were good to go live and we would raise a change request to do so. It seems like this is similar to your current approach so I'm sorry I don't have anything better to offer.

Comment: @ADyson "dump to CSV and file transfer": yes that's also one way we are doing it currently. But the thing is: Its quite time consuming due to data size. also its quite intransparent and people need to know what they are doing which is quite a problem. Our entity relations are so big there is no one who really knows the complete structure of the data. most people are just working in parts of the database.

Comment: maybe you could use transactional replication or log-shipping or something to transfer (certain parts of) the data into another database. Dunno if that's practical in your scenario but it's another way to move data around which is perhaps a bit less time-consuming.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179042/discussion-between-phillip-and-adyson).

Comment: @BagusTesa when referring other sites, it is often helpful to point that [cross-posting is frowned upon](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/cross-posting/info)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome to the pains of development for a Stateful entity like a database. :) RedGate makes a tool called SQL Source Control that is good for moving changed data and Schema into Production, and it can interface with source control solutions such as GIT. It's a bit pricey, but it's the best I've found. One option for keeping dev up to date with prod data and dev changes is one I concocted at my last place of employment, which was... not 100% perfect, but better than nothing, and free. It was developed in Powershell, and it went something like this:

1. Create Pre-restore, Pre-dacpac and Post-dacpac SQL scripts to store data and 
   permission diffs between dev and prod
2. Use SQLPackage.EXE to make DacPac of Dev(Dacpac is basically an xml schema of db, no 
   data)
3. Execute Pre-restore Proc (Often copying out test data that needs to be persisted)
4. Restore Prod over Dev
5. Execute Pre-dacpac script (any DDL That could cause data loss may need to go here)
6. Use SQLPackage.EXE to apply DacPac made in step 2 to Newly restored database
7. Execute Post-Dacpac Script (Permissions, restoration of data copied in step 3)

Again, like I said, it worked and automated the restoration of prod data into our dev environment while keeping our dev changes intact, but it required a good bit of upkeep and maintenance. Also, keep in mind, once your DB reaches a certain size, doing a nightly restore is no longer a viable option due to the time it takes to restore.

Comment: Agree completely about  RedGate Toolbelt

Comment: Taking a look at RedGate-Sql-Source-Control it's looking very promising. (and price).
Dose the Powershell version require forenkeys? (I guess the RedGate tool is fine without)

Comment: No, it doesn't.